# Entity Framework generating sql queries without where clauses

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework 4.3 in one of my data access classes I have generic a function like this

```
    public List<Company> Query(Func<Company, bool> expression)
    {
        return MyDbContext.Instance().Company.Where(expression).ToList();
    }
```

I use it from the bussines layer classes as MyDAL.Query(a => a.Name.Contains(textToSearch)).

Despite ofEntity Framework return the correct results, I don't know why it instead of generate a Sql query sentence with Where clause like "Where name like '%' + textToSearch + '%'", It generates a sql query sentence without a where clause query all the table rows. Obviously this is very inneficient.

By the other way if in my data access clases I write a method like this:

```
    public List<Company> GetLikeName(string textToSearch)
    {
        return MyDbContext.Instance().Company.Where(a => a.Contains(textToSearch)).ToList();
    }
```

It generates correctly a Sql with where like clause.

Why If I use my generic query to retrieve results from database especifying the expression to query from my bussiness classes it generates a Sql sentence without where clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the expression parameter as an `Expression<>`:

```
public List<Company> Query(Expression<Func<Company, bool>> expression)
```

If you just pass a `Func<>`, then `IEnumerable.Where` is called instead of `IQueryable.Where`, and it runs in code, not in SQL.